# Toggle between two or more functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggle

The following code doesn't seem to work for jQuery versions higher than 1.8. Can someone explain how can we get the same functionality from newer versions, though?
Also, shouldn't we have a structure like **element.click(function(){element.toggle();})** ? Why is the toggle() method alone working on click, without actually specifying a .click() method before it?

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: orange;"></div>
```

JS

```
$("div").toggle(
  function () {
    $(this).css({"background":"blue"});
  },
  function () {
    $(this).css({"background":"red"});
  },
  function () {
    $(this).css({"background":"yellow"});
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
var count = 0;

function changeBackground() {
  var color = "";
  switch (count % 3) {
    case 0:
      color = "blue";
      break;
    case 1:
      color = "red";
      break;
    case 2:
      color = "yellow";
      break;
  }
  $("#content").css("background", color);
  count++;
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" onclick="changeBackground()"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't try to deal with raw CSS properties, this is really inflexible approach. Avoid `$.fn.css` method for styling. You should use classes with necessary styles, background, color, etc.

Now, the simple and effective solution I can think of is to use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method like this:

```
var classes = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow'];

$("div").toggleClass(function(i, oldClass) {
    var newClass = classes[(classes.indexOf(oldClass) + 1) % classes.length]
    return oldClass + ' ' + newClass;
});
```

Here is a simple demo that toggles classes on each click.

```js
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  
    var classes = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow'];

    $("div").toggleClass(function(i, oldClass) {
        var newClass = classes[(classes.indexOf(oldClass) + 1) % classes.length]
        return oldClass + ' ' + newClass;
    });
  
});
```

```css
div {padding: 20px; border: 1px #DDD solid;}

.blue {background: blue;}
.red {background: red;}
.yellow {background: yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

<button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

The benefit here is that you can toggle as many classes (not only 3) as you wich, just add new class to classes array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The toggle css styling approach was just for testing purposes. The objective itself is to toggle different functions.

Comment: How are you going to call these functions, some click?